# Issue with React Native Modal Not Covering Status Bar on Android but working fine on iOS

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm encountering a strange issue with the React Native Modal component on Android devices, where it doesn't cover the entire screen including the status bar area, leaving a gap at the top. Interestingly, this issue does not occur on iOS, where the modal behaves as expected and covers the whole screen.

Android (the app it self covers the whole sceen, but not the modal reaches up to right below native top status bar)

[image]

on iOS (modal covers the whole screen as expected)

[image]

I'm using expo file routing. I have two screens, Home and Settings and I want to show Modal in Home. I'm using tabs for navigation of these screens and expo file routing to navigate, could this have something to do with messing up the modal covarage of the whole screen?

```
export default function SimplePopup() {
  return (
    <Modal visible={true} transparent={true}>
      <View style={styles.modalOverlay}>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Simple Popup 123</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalOverlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#272745',
  },
  content: {
  },
  text: {
    color: '#d5dbeb',
    fontSize: 25,
    fontFamily: 'Inter900Black',
  },
})
```

Homescreen launches the popup

```
export default function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SimplePopup></SimplePopup>
      </View>
    </>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#272727',
  },
  content: {
    gap: 10,
    padding: 10,
  },
  column: {
    gap: 10,
  },
})
```

TabsLayout hodling HomeScreen and SettingsScreen

```
const TabsLayout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Tabs
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          headerTintColor: 'white',
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#272727' },
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          tabBarActiveTintColor: '#a6b7ee',
          tabBarStyle: {
            // height: 70,
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderColor: '#555',
            borderTopColor: '#222',
            backgroundColor: '#222',
            position: 'absolute',
            // height: 50,
          },
          tabBarLabelStyle: {
            flexDirection: 'column',
            // fontSize: 7,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            // marginBottom: 10,
          },
        }}
      >
        <Tabs.Screen
          name='home'
          options={{
            title: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Ionicons name='home' size={size} color={color} />,
          }}
        />
        <Tabs.Screen
          name='settings'
          options={{
            title: 'Settings',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Ionicons name='settings' size={size} color={color} />,
          }}
        />
      </Tabs>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the **statusBarTranslucent** prop. This prop allows the modal to extend beneath the status bar, ensuring it covers the entire screen. Here's an example:

```
<Modal {...props} statusBarTranslucent>
  {/* Modal content */}
</Modal>
```

Comment: you saved me hours! best regards.